# Safe way to save/display html content in web portal asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, xss

I am making a web portal so I want to clarify some things. What is the safest way/approach to save `Html` content in database and to display it for other users. I have already started to make two separate applications such as **CMS** and portal site that shows administered content.

I know that I have to save content in unencoded form, but is there any library that checks or filter allowed tags because I want to avoid `XSS` vulnerability as much as possible? Also what is the downside of using `@Html.Raw()` for displaying the data?

Comment: Reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814.aspx and the NuGet package http://nuget.org/packages/AntiXSS

Comment: I have seen it but does it have any vulnerabilites?

Comment: Microsoft is including it as part of ASP.NET 4.5 as the way to prevent XSS: http://www.devproconnections.com/article/aspnet2/microsoft-adds-antixss-aspnet-45-140888, so I think you're safe. Also some good security examples at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials

Comment: I have already seen some tips from Adam Tuliper and seen some examples of AntiXSS use but i wanted to see other ppl opinion and experience of using it thanks.

Comment: About a year ago IBM found a vulnerability but it was patched. http://blog.watchfire.com/wfblog/2012/01/microsoft-anti-xss-library-bypass.html but briefly an update to the library was stripping out pretty much everything. That's the only issue I've encountered. I use it to safe encode HTML input from users before storing in db.

Comment: I have already seen that and that is promising. When u store HTML encoded by AntiXSS in database you after get it from database, decode it and show as content in view

Comment: No. You'll display the safe encoded HTML.

Comment: I'd post my comments but seems you've already seen them :)

Comment: Ps encode before showing not before saving - otherwise searching is a pain and you will at some point suffer from double encoding issues

Comment: @AdamTuliper Sry for confusion I meant using something like SafeHtmlFrag b4 saving, not HTML encoding.

Comment: ah in that case its ok, realize though it won't remove everything, just at least 'something'

Comment: Adam i have seen your video on channel 9 so i am trying now to implement some stuff on my own i'll have more questions when i touch this part it is good to have u guys here rlly :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use AntiXSS library (can by found [here](http://wpl.codeplex.com/)). For me works perfect.
Hope it will help.